# Can Googlebot crawl content from JS fetch?

Tags: googlebot, googlebot-mobile

In my website for many pages, on page load I would call [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in JS to get the data from the server and then render it. I wonder whether Googlebot can crawl content from fetch? I have tried to search online but could not find an answer specifically for fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Googlebot does support fetch as long as you do it as the page loads.

Best thing to do is test. Run a page through a Googlebot based tool like the Mobile Friendly Test and see if your content shows.